# Is there any scenario in which ON CONCLICT happens in a REPLACE statement?

Tags: database, replace

I was wondering if there's any case where we could manage the conflict that could happen in an `INSERT OR REPLACE` (or just `REPLACE`). I've just seen a fragment of a friend's code such as:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE table(params) VALUES(values) ON CONFLICT(key) DO UPDATE SET param=value ...
```

Doesn't `REPLACE` manage the conflict implicitly? Is it really necessary to have that `UPDATE` clause or is it redundant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized that `REPLACE` deletes the record before doing an `INSERT`. So I guess that I'll have to stick with `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE` as I need to maintain the old data as well.